# Best way to fix PHP error Undefined index - PHP 5.5

Tags: php

I have noticed some error logs since I tried a new open source trade script and I tried to fix them. Most of them are "Undefined property", "Undefined index" and "Undefined variable". So, I tried this answer ([PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)) and now there are no error logs, but I am not sure if this is going to work without no issues. Here is the file's source code and bellow is my fix which I don't know if it is correct.
Please take a short look if you can. Thank you.

*PHP errors:*

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index: method in /var/www/html/security.php on line 379
PHP Notice: Undefined index: method in /var/www/html/security.php on line 380
PHP Notice: Undefined index: method in /var/www/html/security.php on line 381
```

*Full Code:*

```
<?php
include_once '../lib/common.php';

if (User::$info['locked'] == 'Y' || User::$info['deactivated'] == 'Y')
    Link::redirect('settings.php');
elseif (User::$awaiting_token)
    Link::redirect('verify-token.php');
elseif (!User::isLoggedIn())
    Link::redirect('login.php');

$step1 = false;
$step2 = false;
$step3 = false;
$step4 = false;

$authcode1 = (!empty($_REQUEST['authcode'])) ? urldecode($_REQUEST['authcode']) : false;
if ($authcode1 && empty($_REQUEST['step'])) {
    API::add('User','getSettingsChangeRequest',array(urlencode($authcode1)));
    $query = API::send();
    $response = unserialize(base64_decode($query['User']['getSettingsChangeRequest']['results'][0]));
    if ($response) {
        if (!empty($response['authy']))
            $step1 = true;
        elseif (!empty($response['google']))
            $step3 = true;
    }
    else
        Errors::add(Lang::string('settings-request-expired'));
}

$cell1 = (!empty($_REQUEST['cell'])) ? preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$_REQUEST['cell']) : false;
$country_code1 = (!empty($_REQUEST['country_code'])) ? preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$_REQUEST['country_code']) : false;
$token1 = (!empty($_REQUEST['token'])) ? preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$_REQUEST['token']) : false;
$remove = !empty($_REQUEST['remove']);

if ($remove) {
    if (empty($_REQUEST['submitted']) || (!empty($_REQUEST['method']) && $_REQUEST['method'] == 'sms')) {
        if (User::$info['using_sms'] == 'Y') {
            if (User::sendSMS()) {
                $sent_sms = true;
                Messages::add(Lang::string('withdraw-sms-sent'));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!($token1 > 0))
            Errors::add(Lang::string('security-no-token'));

        if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
            API::token($token1);
            API::add('User','disable2fa');
            $query = API::send();

            if ($query['error'] == 'security-incorrect-token')
                Errors::add(Lang::string('security-incorrect-token'));

            if ($query['error'] == 'security-com-error')
                Errors::add(Lang::string('security-com-error'));

            if ($query['error'] == 'authy-errors')
                Errors::merge($query['authy_errors']);

            if ($query['error'] == 'request-expired')
                Errors::add(Lang::string('settings-request-expired'));

            if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
                Link::redirect('security.php?message=security-disabled-message');
            }
        }
    }
}

if (!empty($_REQUEST['step']) && $_REQUEST['step'] == 1) {
    if (!($cell1 > 0) && $_REQUEST['method'] != 'google')
        Errors::add(Lang::string('security-no-cell'));
    if (!($country_code1 > 0) && $_REQUEST['method'] != 'google')
        Errors::add(Lang::string('security-no-cc'));

    if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
        if ($_REQUEST['method'] != 'google') {
            API::add('User','registerAuthy',array($cell1,$country_code1));
            $query = API::send();
            $authy_id = $query['User']['registerAuthy']['results'][0]['user']['id'];
            $response = $query['User']['registerAuthy']['results'][0];

            if (!$response || !is_array($response))
                Errors::merge(Lang::string('security-com-error'));

            if ($response['success'] == 'false')
                Errors::merge($response['errors']);
        }

        if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
            if ($_REQUEST['method'] != 'google') {
                if ($_REQUEST['method'] == 'sms') {
                    if (User::sendSMS($authy_id))
                        $using_sms = 'Y';
                }
                else
                    $using_sms = 'N';

                if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
                    API::add('User','enableAuthy',array($cell1,$country_code1,$authy_id,$using_sms));
                    API::add('User','settingsEmail2fa',array(array('authy'=>1),1));
                    $query = API::send();
                    //$step1 = true;

                    if ($query['User']['settingsEmail2fa']['results'][0])
                        Link::redirect('security.php?notice=email');
                }
            }
            else {
                if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
                    API::add('User','enableGoogle2fa',array($cell1,$country_code1));
                    API::add('User','settingsEmail2fa',array(array('google'=>1),1));
                    $query = API::send();
                    //$step1 = true;

                    if ($query['User']['settingsEmail2fa']['results'][0])
                        Link::redirect('security.php?notice=email');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['step']) && $_REQUEST['step'] == 2) {
    if (!($token1 > 0))
        Errors::add(Lang::string('security-no-token'));

    if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
        API::settingsChangeId($authcode1);
        API::token($token1);
        API::add('User','verifiedAuthy');
        $query = API::send();

        if (!empty($query['error'])) {
            if ($query['error'] == 'security-com-error')
                Errors::add(Lang::string('security-com-error'));

            if ($query['error'] == 'authy-errors')
                Errors::merge($query['authy_errors']);

            if ($query['error'] == 'request-expired')
                Errors::add(Lang::string('settings-request-expired'));
        }

        if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
            Messages::add(Lang::string('security-success-message'));

            $step2 = true;
        }
        else
            $step1 = true;
    }
    else
        $step1 = true;
}
elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['step']) && $_REQUEST['step'] == 3) {
    if (!($token1 > 0))
        Errors::add(Lang::string('security-no-token'));

    if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
        API::settingsChangeId($authcode1);
        API::token($token1);
        API::add('User','verifiedGoogle');
        $query = API::send();

        if ($query['error'] == 'security-incorrect-token')
            Errors::add(Lang::string('security-incorrect-token'));

        if ($query['error'] == 'request-expired')
            Errors::add(Lang::string('settings-request-expired'));

        if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) {
            Messages::add(Lang::string('security-success-message'));

            $step4 = true;
        }
        else
            $step3 = true;
    }
    else
        $step3 = true;
}

if (!empty($_REQUEST['notice']) && $_REQUEST['notice'] == 'email')
    $notice = Lang::string('settings-change-notice');
elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['message']) && $_REQUEST['message'] == 'security-disabled-message')
    Messages::add(Lang::string('security-disabled-message'));

if (User::$info['verified_authy'] == 'Y' || $step2)
    API::add('Content','getRecord',array('security-setup'));
elseif (User::$info['verified_google'] == 'Y' || $step4)
    API::add('Content','getRecord',array('security-setup-google'));
elseif ($step1)
    API::add('Content','getRecord',array('security-token'));
elseif ($step3) {
    API::add('Content','getRecord',array('security-google'));
    API::add('User','getGoogleSecret');
}
else
    API::add('Content','getRecord',array('security-explain'));

$query = API::send();
$content = $query['Content']['getRecord']['results'][0];
$secret = (!empty($query['User']['getGoogleSecret'])) ? $query['User']['getGoogleSecret']['results'][0] : false;
$page_title = Lang::string('security');

include 'includes/head.php';
?>
<div class="page_title">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title"><h1><?= $page_title ?></h1></div>
        <div class="pagenation">&nbsp;<a href="index.php"><?= Lang::string('home') ?></a> <i>/</i> <a href="account.php"><?= Lang::string('account') ?></a> <i>/</i> <a href="security.php"><?= $page_title ?></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <? include 'includes/sidebar_account.php'; ?>
    <div class="content_right">
        <div class="testimonials-4">
        <? if ($remove) { ?>
            <? Errors::display(); ?>
            <div class="buyform">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3 class="section_label">
                            <span class="left"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <span class="right"><?= Lang::string('security-enter-token') ?></span>
                        </h3>
                        <form id="enable_tfa" action="security.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="remove" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
                            <div class="buyform">
                                <div class="one_half">
                                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                                    <div class="param">
                                        <label for="token"><?= Lang::string('security-token') ?></label>
                                        <input name="token" id="token" type="text" value="<?= $token1 ?>" />
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="mar_top2"></div>
                                     <ul class="list_empty">
                                        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?= Lang::string('security-validate') ?>" class="but_user" /></li>
                                        <? if (User::$info['using_sms'] == 'Y') { ?>
                                        <li><input type="submit" name="sms" value="<?= Lang::string('security-resend-sms') ?>" class="but_user" /></li>
                                        <? } ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <? } elseif (User::$info['verified_authy'] == 'Y' || $step2) { ?>
            <h2><?= $content['title'] ?></h2>
            <div class="text"><?= $content['content'] ?></div>
            <div class="mar_top2"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <? Messages::display(); ?>
            <ul class="list_empty">
                <li><div class="number">+<?= User::$info['country_code']?> <?= User::$info['tel']?></div></li>
                <li><a class="item_label" href="javascript:return false;"><?= Lang::string('security-verified') ?></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="list_empty">
                <li><a href="security.php?remove=1" class="but_user"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i> <?= Lang::string('security-disable') ?></a></li>
            </ul>
        <? } elseif (User::$info['verified_google'] == 'Y' || $step4) { ?>
            <h2><?= $content['title'] ?></h2>
            <div class="text"><?= $content['content'] ?></div>
            <div class="mar_top2"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <? Messages::display(); ?>
            <ul class="list_empty">
                <li><a href="security.php?remove=1" class="but_user"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i> <?= Lang::string('security-disable') ?></a></li>
            </ul>
        <? } elseif ($step1) { ?>
            <h2><?= $content['title'] ?></h2>
            <div class="text"><?= $content['content'] ?></div>
            <div class="mar_top2"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <? Errors::display(); ?>
            <form id="enable_tfa" action="security.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="authcode" value="<?= urlencode($authcode1) ?>" />
                <div class="buyform">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3 class="section_label">
                            <span class="left"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <span class="right"><?= Lang::string('security-enter-token') ?></span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="one_half">
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="param">
                                <label for="authy-token"><?= Lang::string('security-token') ?></label>
                                <input name="token" id="authy-token" type="text" value="<?= $token1 ?>" />
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="mar_top2"></div>
                             <ul class="list_empty">
                                <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?= Lang::string('security-validate') ?>" class="but_user" /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        <? } elseif ($step3) { ?>
            <h2><?= $content['title'] ?></h2>
            <div class="text"><?= $content['content'] ?></div>
            <div class="mar_top2"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <? Errors::display(); ?>
            <form id="enable_tfa" action="security.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="3" />
                <input type="hidden" name="authcode" value="<?= urlencode($authcode1) ?>" />
                <div class="buyform">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3 class="section_label">
                            <span class="left"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <span class="right"><?= Lang::string('security-scan-qr') ?></span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="one_half">
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="param">
                                <label for="secret"><?= Lang::string('security-secret-code') ?></label>
                                <input type="text" id="secret" name="secret" value="<?= $secret['secret'] ?>" />
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="calc">
                                <img class="qrcode" src="includes/qrcode.php?sec=1&code=otpauth://totp/<?= $secret['label'] ?>?secret=<?= $secret['secret'] ?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="param">
                                <label for="token"><?= Lang::string('security-token') ?></label>
                                <input name="token" id="token" type="text" value="<?= $token1 ?>" />
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="mar_top2"></div>
                             <ul class="list_empty">
                                <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?= Lang::string('security-validate') ?>" class="but_user" /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        <? } else { ?>
            <?= (!empty($notice)) ? '<div class="notice"><div class="message-box-wrap">'.$notice.'</div></div>' : '' ?>
            <? Errors::display(); ?>
            <? Messages::display(); ?>
            <h2><?= $content['title'] ?></h2>
            <div class="text"><?= $content['content'] ?></div>
            <div class="mar_top2"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <form name="start_auth" id="enable_tfa" action="security.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" id="send_sms" name="send_sms" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="google_2fa" name="google_2fa" value="" />
                <div class="buyform">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3 class="section_label">
                            <span class="left"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <span class="right"><?= Lang::string('security-enable-two-factor') ?></span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="one_half">
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="param">
                                <label for="method"><?= Lang::string('security-method') ?></label>
                                <select name="method" id="method">
                                    <option <?= ($_REQUEST['method'] == 'google') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="google">Google Authenticator</option>
                                    <option <?= ($_REQUEST['method'] == 'authy') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="authy">Authy</option>
                                    <option <?= ($_REQUEST['method'] == 'SMS') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="SMS">SMS</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="param method_show" style="display:none;">
                                <label for="authy-countries"><?= Lang::string('security-country') ?> (<?= Lang::string('security-optional-google') ?>)</label>
                                <select name="country_code" id="authy-countries">
                                <? 
                                if ($country_code1 > 0) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$country_code1.'" selected="selected"></option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                                </select>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="param method_show" style="display:none;">
                                <label for="authy-cellphone"><?= Lang::string('security-cell') ?> (<?= Lang::string('security-optional-google') ?>)</label>
                                <input name="cell" id="authy-cellphone" type="text" value="<?= $cell1 ?>" />
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="mar_top2"></div>
                             <ul class="list_empty">
                                <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?= Lang::string('security-enable') ?>" class="but_user" /></li>
                                <!-- li><input type="submit" name="google" value="<?= Lang::string('security-enable-google') ?>" class="but_user" /></li -->
                                <!--  li><input type="submit" name="sms" value="<?= Lang::string('security-send-sms') ?>" class="but_user" /></li -->
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        <? } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="mar_top8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<? include 'includes/foot.php'; ?>
```

Error lines:

```
<option <?= ($_REQUEST['method'] == 'google') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="google">Google Authenticator</option>
<option <?= ($_REQUEST['method'] == 'authy') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="authy">Authy</option>
<option <?= ($_REQUEST['method'] == 'SMS') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="SMS">SMS</option>
```

My fix (I added "!empty($_REQUEST['method']) && "):

```
<option <?= (!empty($_REQUEST['method']) && $_REQUEST['method'] == 'google') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="google">Google Authenticator</option>
<option <?= (!empty($_REQUEST['method']) && $_REQUEST['method'] == 'authy') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="authy">Authy</option>
<option <?= (!empty($_REQUEST['method']) && $_REQUEST['method'] == 'SMS') ? 'selected="selected"' : false ?> value="SMS">SMS</option>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: @Martijn, yeah, that's the OP also said in the question.

Comment: @axiac That doesn't make it any less of a duplicate. My reading of the question is "I fixed it. Did I fix it?"

Comment: You should use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), not [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) but in this case the result is the same.

Comment: Unrelated but a heads up... PHP 5.5 has been at end of life for awhile now. Your application could potentially be at risk due to unpatched vulnerabilities.

Comment: @ceejayoz as you say. As far as I remember, the "duplicate" question doesn't ask "Did I fix it?".

Comment: Undefined index error means that you don't have the key in an array you refered to. That could be fixed via `isset($variable)` function. It checks if a variable or a key of an array variable exists. `empty` just checks if a string or an array is empty. Null values can be checked via `is_null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got error because you were trying to access array index, which doesn't exist, so

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Like below

```
(isset($_REQUEST['method']) && $_REQUEST['method'] == 'google')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. So, I only add "isset" and is fixed without not further modification right?

Comment: Ok, I change it to isset and it works great. I am going to do the same with other errors too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you have understood the reason for the notice; you attempt to access a array index that is not there. The only fix for this is to make sure the index exists before trying to fetch it. This is considered good practice either way and you should adapt to this approach: never access indexes you can not guarantee exist.

The most common pattern is to do something like:

```
$methodValue = null;
if (isset($_REQUEST['method']) and strlen($_REQUEST['method']) > 0) {
    $methodValue = $_REQUEST['method'];
}
```

This will not throw any notices, and you always know the value of the variable regardless if the index exists or not. This variable also provides a default value, which accessing the index can not.